# Extracting typescript exports to json file using gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, typescript, gulp

I have several typescript files, some of them export a certain var - named APIS - which is an array of objects.
I want to extract the values of all of these exports, and pipe them to a json file using gulp.

For example, I have a folder named services, with 3 files: service1.ts, service2.ts, service3.ts.

**service1.ts:**

```
...
export const APIS = [ { "field1" : "blabla" } ];
```

**service2.ts:**

```
...
export const APIS = [ { "field2" : "yadayada" }, { "field3" : "yadabla" } ];
```

**service3.ts:** - does not export the APIS var.

I want to use gulp in oder create a json file that looks something like this:

```
[ { "field1" : "blabla" }, { "field2" : "yadayada" }, { "field3" : "yadabla" } ]
```

**gulpfile.js** - the ??? is a placeholder for the missing code.

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('.../services/*.ts')
            .pipe(???)
            .pipe(concat('export.json'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./test'));
});
```

I'm new to both typescript & gulp, so I'm not sure how to achieve this... any ideas? :)

**EDIT:** So, I understand that there's no OOTB solution for this, and I need to writer my own task / plugin. I'm not really sure how to achieve that, though.
Ideally, what I want is to find a gulp plugin (or a combination of plugins) that can handle ts / js files as objects with properties. Then I can extract the var I need from the file.

I couldn't really find something like that, only string manipulation plugins - Treating my ts file as a string and using search with regex seems overly complicated to me. Is there something I'm missing here? is there a more straight-forward way to do this?

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you want to compiling typescript to js and put it in a json file?

Comment: I don't. I just want to create a json file out of the APIS vars.

Comment: Alright, you're going to need a gulp plugin that can search through your ts files and extract the APIS const's however I can't think of a plugin off the top of my head that you could use to do that, you may need to make your own if you definitely need to do this to solve your current needs

Comment: Ok...still not sure exactly how to do that. Maybe I'm missing something, but is there a simple way to load a js / ts file to a json object (with properties) using gulp?

Comment: Gulp works via a plugin system, people make plugins and you leverage those plugins in your code to do the nice things you want -- If I was you i'd start searching the internet for a gulp plugin that does what you just asked, from my knowledge there isn't one and if you want to do what you're suggesting you'll need to make the gulp plugin and then use it in your gulpfile. [Here is a link to some docs on making a gulp plugin](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/writing-a-plugin/README.md)

Comment: I couldn't find one, which is why I asked  a question here. :)

Comment: well i'd recommend you looking at the link in my previous comment -- it still start to put you down the path of writing your own gulp plugin to do what you described, I can't imagine it'll be that difficult, the javascript involved isn't complex and it should be an overall straight forward process

Comment: please see the edit to my original question

Comment: Converting it to a string and using regex is one way of doing it however if you're finding that complex I think you're going to need to just knuckle down and try and understand these concepts so that you can implement your own version, there is no short and sweet plugin without someone first doing the work, you're the first person to hit this use case so you may as well buckle down and make it then make it available for whoever might hit this problem later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing, and it worked for me. I'm positing it here in case anyone else finds it useful. :)

Instead of .ts, I saved the exports in .js files, i.e:

service2.export.js:

```
exports.APIS = [ { "field2" : "yadayada" }, { "field3" : "yadabla" } ];
```

Based on the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36869651/3007732 I created a gulp task as following:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var map = require('gulp-map');
var fs = require('fs');

var allServices;

gulp.task('default', function() {

    var allServices = [];

    var stream = gulp.src('./**/*.export.js')
        .pipe(map(function(file) {
            var obj = require(file.path);
            if (obj.APIS != null) {
                allServices.push.apply(allServices, obj.APIS);
            }
            return file;
        }));

    stream.on("end", function (cb)
    {   
        fs.writeFile('./export.json', JSON.stringify(allServices), cb);
    });

    return stream;
});
```

and now I get the following output in export.json:

```
[ { "field1" : "blabla" }, { "field2" : "yadayada" }, { "field3" : "yadabla" } ]
```

which is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The typescript [compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) is relevant here, as this is what you need to parse and understand the ts-code properly. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a gulp plugin that implements this API.

I think your best bet is to change strategy completely here and solve your problem in another way, or to use regex to try to extract the constants that you want. Unless you want to write your own gulp-plugin using the compiler API.