# Accessing typescript file variable values using gulp

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-plugin

I have several typescript files, some of them export a const named `APIS`.

I'm trying to access those exports (I want to concatenated all of them to a single file), but it doesn't seem to work. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what.

For example, I have a folder named services, with 2 files: service1.ts, service2.ts.

**service1.ts:**

```
...
export const APIS = [ { "field1" : "blabla" } ];
```

**service2.ts:** does not contain the `APIS` var.

This is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var map = require('gulp-map');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src('.../services/*.ts')
        .pipe(map(function(file) {
            return file.APIS;
          }))
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./test/'));
});
```

When I run this task, I get nothing. When I added `console.log(file.APIS);` to the map function, I get `undefined` for all the values (although it is defined in service1.ts!).

This is following to: [Extracting typescript exports to json file using gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843151/extracting-typescript-exports-to-json-file-using-gulp)

**EDIT:** OK, so I tried saving the exports in a .js file instead of a .ts file, and now I can access those vars using `require`:

gulp.task('default', function() {

```
  return gulp.src('./**/*.service.export.js')
        .pipe(map(function(file) {
            var fileObj = require(file.path);
            ...
          }))
```

Now if I try `console.log(fileObj.APIS);` I get the correct values. What I'm still confused about is how I can pass these value on, and create a single file out of all these vars. Is it possible to push them into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work as you think it would work. Gulp itself knows nothing about typescript files, that file is a [vinyl-file](https://medium.com/@contrahacks/gulp-3828e8126466#.btj4m4na0) and has no knowledge about the typescript code within its content.

**Edit**

Based on your example, you can do something like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var map = require('gulp-map');
var fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('test', function ()
{
    var allConstants = [];
    var stream = gulp.src('./**/*.service.export.js')
        .pipe(map(function(file)
        {
            var obj = require(file.path);
            if (obj.APIS != null)
                allConstants = allConstants.concat(obj.APIS);
            return file;
        }));

    stream.on("end", function (cb)
    {
        // Do your own formatting here
        var content = allConstants.map(function (constants)
        {
            return Object.keys(constants).reduce(function (aggregatedString, key)
            {
                return aggregatedString + key + " : " + constants[key];
            }, "");
        }).join(", ");

        fs.writeFile('filename.txt', content, cb);
    });
    return stream;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to work around this issue: If I save the exports in a .js file instead of .ts file I can access them using require. Now my problem is how to collect all those vars into a single json file.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion**

If you want to collect multiple variables into a single file i.e. a common variables file I suggest [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace).

**Steps**

Create a file, require it and use tags within that file to place your variables.

**Advice**

If you are already using services don't create an array. Instead create an object (JSON) where every property is a constant. i.e.

```
var constants =  {
   const_1: 0,
   const_2: 1,
   const_3: 2,
}
```